# Faster way to change each value in dataframe ACCORDING to original value

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe with 30000 columns and 4000 rows. Each cell entry contains an integer. For EVERY entry, I want to multiply the original contents with log(k/m),

where k is the total number of rows ie.4000
and m is the total number of non zero rows for THAT PARTICULAR COLUMN.

My current code uses apply:

```
for column in df.columns:
    m = len(df[column].to_numpy().nonzero())
    df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: x * np.log10(4000/m))
```

This takes me hours (????). I hope there is some faster way to do it, anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Please create a sample 5 row dataframe and paste it here as text. Also show the final output, may be you will get better help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First generate sample data:

```
np.random.seed(123)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4, 5)*500, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']).astype(int).replace(range(100, 200), 0)

Result:

    A   B   C   D   E
0   348 0   0   275 359
1   211 490 342 240 0
2   0   364 219 29  0
3   368 91  87  265 265
```

Next I define a vector with containing the non-zero column counts:

```
non_zeros = df.ne(0).sum().values

# Giving me: array([3, 3, 3, 4, 2], dtype=int64)
```

From there I find the log-factor to each column:

```
faktor = np.mat(np.log10(len(df)/ non_zeros))

# giving me: matrix([[0.12493874, 0.12493874, 0.12493874, 0.        , 0.30103   ]])
```

Then multiplying each column with it's factor and converting back to DataFrame:

```
res = np.multiply(np.mat(df), faktor)
df = pd.DataFrame(res)
```

With this solution you come around the non-tight loops in Python.

Hope it will bring some help.

Answer (score 0):

***@Dennis Hansen***'s answer is good, but if you're still need to iterate over column I would recommend not to use `apply` in your solution.

```
a = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10000)) # define an arib. dataframe
a.iloc[5:500] = 0 # set some values to zero
```

Solution with apply performance:

```
>> %%timeit
>> b = a.apply(lambda x: x * np.log10(10000/len(a.to_numpy().nonzero())))
1.53 ms ± 3.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Solution without apply performance:

```
>> %%timeit
>> b = a*np.log10(10000/len(a.to_numpy().nonzero()))
849 µs ± 3.74 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```